# Import custom jackson serializer (Module) in webflutest Springboot 3.2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, jackson-databind, jackson-modules

I have an application in webflux and SpringBoot 3.2

i have custom Jackson Module and serializer, ubfortunately when i try to execute test no serializer found

Custom module

```
package ae.company.banking.configuration.converters;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new MoneyModule());
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

DeSerializer

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.money.CurrencyUnit;
import javax.money.Monetary;
import org.javamoney.moneta.Money;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MoneyDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Money> {

    @Override
    public Money deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        JsonNode node = p.getCodec().readTree(p);
        double amount = node.get("amount").asDouble();
        String currencyCode = node.get("currency").asText();

        CurrencyUnit currency = Monetary.getCurrency(currencyCode);
        return Money.of(amount, currency);
    }
}
```

The module

```
package ae.company.banking.configuration.converters;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import org.javamoney.moneta.Money;

public class MoneyModule extends SimpleModule {
    public MoneyModule() {
        addSerializer( Money.class, new MoneySerializer());
        addDeserializer( Money.class, new MoneyDeserializer());
    }
}
```

my test

```
@WebFluxTest( controllers = UserController.class )
@Import( { JacksonConfig.class, FindUserById.class, FindAllUsers.class, AddUserAccount.class, AddUserBeneficiary.class, WebFluxControllerSecurityTestConfig.class } )
class UserControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    UserController controller;

    @MockBean
    UserRepository repository;

    @MockBean
    JwtTokenFilter filter;

    @Test
    @WithMockUser
    void testGetgetUserById() {
        CurrencyUnit eur = Monetary.getCurrency( "EUR" );

        var user = User.builder()
                .id( "4787889456456456456frfrfrf582" )
                .identityId( "iyioyuy9y98y9y9" )
                .firstName( "firstname2" )
                .lastName( "lastname2" )
                .role( Role.USER )
      .balance( Money.of( 200, eur ) )
                .username( "test2@test.com" ).build();
        when( repository.findById( "4787889456456456456frfrfrf87" ) )
                .thenReturn( Mono.just( user ) );

        var testClient = WebTestClient.bindToController( controller ).webFilter( new SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter() )
                .apply( springSecurity() )
                .build();
        testClient
                .get().uri( "/api/v1/users/4787889456456456456frfrfrf87" )
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
                .expectBodyList( UserDto.class )
                .hasSize( 1 );
        Mockito.verify( repository, times( 1 ) ).findById( "4787889456456456456frfrfrf87" );
    }
```

And the error

Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `javax.money.MonetaryAmount` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information

Comment: Remove `JacksonConfig` add `MoneyModule` as a bean and it will be automatically used. Remove the `WebTestClient` binding, autowire the `WebTestClient` instead.

Comment: the last point is not possible because spring security will not work otherwise....and i manage to make it work by injecting in test. can i also add javatime module as a bean?

Comment: Spring Security will work perfectly fine if you configured it properly, webfluxtest will detect it. JavaTime isn't needed as a module as it will be automatically added when detected.

Comment: javatime module is come from jackson jsr310 lib in dependencies, and it i snot injected how it can be found automatically ? you have to add as a module, i will try your soltution

Comment: No you don't need to add it. JavaTime is a well known module and will be added automatically. The problem is you are trying to configure everything manually disabling autoconfiguration and detection.

Comment: ok so just autowire webtest and i ,ust add autoconfiguration annotation on top of test and not adding test securityconfig class

Comment: Only `@WebFluxTest` should be enough.

Comment: following your advice i deleted all annotation just @WebFluxTest; delete all autowired about controller and just inject @WebCLienTest i have a token issue : java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "reactor.core.publisher.Mono.checkpoint(String)" because the return value of "org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter.filter(org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange, org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain)" is null

Comment: You are mocking the `JwtTokenFilter` but don't register any behavior on it and hence it will return `null` as that is the default mocking behavior.

Comment: yes and @WithMockUser("ROLE_USER") should make the job no ? because if i dont mock the filter it is not working, i will try later to use all automatic but for now it is only working manually, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

To make it work ive done this

var testClient = WebTestClient

```
        .bindToController( controller ).webFilter( new SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter() )
        .apply( springSecurity() )
        .build();
testClient
        .mutate()
        .codecs( clientCodecConfigurer ->
                clientCodecConfigurer.defaultCodecs()
                        .jackson2JsonDecoder( new Jackson2JsonDecoder( mapper ) ) ).build()
        .post().uri( "/api/v1/users/4787889456456456456frfrfrf87/SAVING" )
        .exchange()
        .expectStatus().isCreated()
        .expectBodyList( UserDto.class )
        .hasSize( 1 );
Mockito.verify( repository, times( 1 ) ).save( user );
```

and injected mapper

@Autowired
ObjectMapper mapper;

i will try the solution of @M. Deinum